# In selenium is this acceptable to verify ellements present in a page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium.. In my test script there is a page which has many text fields drop down buttons.

I have to verify all that field whether they are present in a page or no. 
I am doing like this:

```
if(webElement.isDisplayed()){ 
   Reporter.log("abc displayed ");      
} else {                
   Reporter.log("abc failed to display");
   Assert.fail();
}
```

Comment: Do not use isdisplayed method to check if element is present. U will get an exception if element is not present. Use the findelements method and check the size of list.

Answer (score 0):

NO,`webElement.isDisplayed()` is judge whether the element is show, if you wanna verify it is present, use this:

```
public WebElement untilAdded(By by) {
        return new FluentWait<SearchContext>(context)
                .withTimeout(timeout, timeUnit)
                .pollingEvery(interval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class)
                .until(new Function<SearchContext, WebElement>() {
                    public WebElement apply(SearchContext context) {
                        return context.findElement(by);
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use WebDriverWait to wait for the appearance of the Element.

```
(new WebDriverWait(driver, 30)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By by));
```

for other ExpectedConditions read the [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) part in the API